# How to add dynamically created ul list to placeholder?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to create a HTML list in code behind in C# and add this list to a placeholder.

My Code:

```
else if (Session["Option"].ToString() == "HTMLList")
{
        //generate HTML list (ul)

        HtmlGenericControl ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");


        ListItemCollection ListItems = new ListItemCollection();
        ListItems = (ListItemCollection)Session["SelectedPupils"];

        foreach (ListItem li in ListItems)
        {
               HtmlGenericControl liInUl = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
               liInUl.InnerText = li.Text;

               //Code to add my liInUl to ul
        }


        placeHolderSelection.Controls.Add(ul);

}
```

How can I get the code working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `liInUl` control to the `ul` control like this:

```
ul.Controls.Add(liInUl);
```